# Angular js Nesting custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested

I want to use something like nesting with custom directives in angular js. Could anyone explain me with simple solution ?

example code is below is not working for me :

```
<outer>
    <inner></inner>
</outer>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.directive('outer',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        template:'<div><h1>i am a outer</h1></div>',
        compile : function(elem,attr){
            return function(scope,elem,att,outercontrol){
                outercontrol.addItem(1);
            }
        },
        controller : function($scope){
            this.addItem = function(val){
                console.log(val);
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive('inner',function(){
    return{
        require : 'outer',
        template : '<div><h1>i am a inner</h1></div>',
        link:function(scope,elem,attr){

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can do it, but what is the problem?

Comment: You have to use transclusion. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: Yes of-course we can do it in angular, I want to know why isn't  working for me. Is there something wrong in the code. I tried transclude to true. It didn't worked.

Comment: @sajankumar what errors are you getting?

Comment: @simpe i don't get any errors. It render only outer directive. I want to render it outer and inner directive kind of nesting. Check my code.

Answer (score 47):

First add `restrict:'E'` to the inner controller to make it accessible as an element.

Then change the `require : 'outer'` into `require : '^outer',` to enable looking for this directive in  parents.

Then you need to use transclude to enable the content of the `<outer>` to be viewed, by the following steps:

1. add `transclude = true` to the outer directive.
2. define where you want the inner data to be viewed. *(I guess you need it to appear after the "i am outer" string so you can modify the template of the outer one to be like this `template:'<div><h1>i am a outer</h1><div ng-transclude></div></div>'`)*.

Then you don't need to the compile parameter at all.
As this variable which called outercontrol will not be called at the outer directive but at the inner directive so there is no need to the compile at all for the outer directive and the inner link function will be modified to be like this:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, outercontrol){
    outercontrol.addItem(1);
}
```

after all  this modification the final code will be like the following:

the **HTML**:

```
<outer>
<inner></inner>
</outer>
```

the **js**:

```
var app = angular.module("exampleApp",[]);
    app.directive('outer', function(){
        return{
            transclude:true,
            restrict:'E',
            template:'<div><h1>i am a outer</h1><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
            controller : function($scope){
                this.addItem = function(val){
                    console.log(val);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    app.directive('inner',function(){
        return{
            restrict:'E',
            require : '^outer',
            template : '<div><h1>i am a inner</h1></div>',
            link:function(scope,elem,attr,outercontrol){
                outercontrol.addItem(1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is what i exactly want. Thank you so much guys (Y).

Comment: @sajankumar You should accept his answer, this was very helpful!

Comment: @Mostafa Ahmed I have a problem: In the outer directive I am using Replace: true, but it does not work.. How can I solve? Thnak you

Answer (score 4):

If you want a simple solution, check out [this plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/vnNvxQ4eG6QcU77cRkUh?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('outer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div style="border-style:solid"><h1>hey</h1><inner></inner></div>',
    }
});

app.directive('inner', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div style="border-style:solid"><h1>i am an inner</h1></div>',
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <outer></outer>
</div>
```

The problem is that you're nuking the  tag with the template attribute of the  directive. This line:

```
    template:'<div><h1>i am a outer</h1></div>',
```

Does that.

Comment: I don't want to nest my directives like your code. I want something like this "<outer><inner></inner></outer>".

Comment: This one is not modular and it is sort of against the point of using directives.. you can put all your logic into one directive then.